# Upper bound of a sum

Tags: inequality

It is given that $\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_i^3 \leq C $

Show that there exist a positive real number $K$ which satisfy the following inequality:

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{x_i}{a x_i + b} \leq K$

Where $a,b,C >0$ and $x_i>0 ;     \forall   i\in\{1,2,3,...,n\}$

I tried to solve this but don't have any idea where to start! I strongly doubt if this inequality is true. Is it possible to disprove in case it's untrue.

Comment: You tagged the question "contest math", is it because you have a source?

Comment: It's from a regional Olympiad according to my friend. But I don't have the exact source and that's why I am removing tag from 'contest-math'.

Comment: Is $K$ allowed to depend on $n$? I assume not, right?

Comment: Does it depend on $a,b$?

Comment: I think $K$ is a constant which depends on $a,b$ and $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ f(x) = \frac{x^{1/3}}{a x^{1/3}+b} $$
is a concave function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence the claim follows from Jensen's inequality. It is enough to take $K$ as:
$$ K=n \frac{(C/n)^{1/3}}{b+a(C/n)^{1/3}}.$$
$K$ *has* to depend on $n$, since otherwise we may take $x_i\approx\frac{1}{i^{2/3}}$ and in such a case
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x_i}{ax_i+b}$$
is not a convergent series, as Vincenzo Oliva pointed in the comments.

Comment: Thanks Jack. It's a great help. But is it possible to find $K$ from given constraint.

Comment: @Ria: $$ K = 3\frac{(C/3)^{1/3}}{a(C/3)^{1/3}+b}.$$

Comment: Almost surely I'm missing something, but consider the following. 

Let $x_i=\displaystyle\frac{1}{i^{2/3}}$. Then $$ \sum_{i=1}^n x_{i}^3 = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2}<\frac{\pi^2}{6}=C.$$ But, with e.g. $a=b=1$, $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac{1/i^{2/3}}{1/i^{2/3}+1}=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{i^{2/3}+1}=\infty,$$ so for large enough $n$ $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^{2/3}+1}>3\frac{(\pi^2/18)^{1/3}}{(\pi^2/18)^{1/3}+1}=K. $$

What am I missing?

Comment: @VincenzoOliva: for some unknown reason I assumed $n=3$. No, well, given a finite $n$, Jensen's inequality gives that our sum is bounded by $$ n \frac{(C/n)^{1/3}}{b+a(C/n)^{1/3}}.$$

Comment: Now I see. Indeed despite having not that much of a practice with Jensen's inequality,I did expect to see $n$. +1, by the way.